# Force update of already installed android app

Tags: java, android, store

I need to force update the apps of all my users that already have the app installed. I have checked https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates, but is it possible to use this library even if the version already out on play store doesn't have this lib installed? Like, do i need an update to implement force update?

Comment: Yeah its a catch 22, you need to ship a version of your app with code in it to force the upgrade, any version before that cannot be forced

Comment: @Blundell Is there any solution to force the already installed app's users to upgrade the app? By any medium like Google play services or anything? This is a big issue and should be solved.

Comment: @Artur Rossi Did you got any way to do this?

Comment: No, its one of the first features you should put into any app :-) (sorry!)

Comment: @SaketKumar no, we made a big effort sending emails and reminders to our users, for them to update the app